# jQuery Validation: determine if field was validated on form submit, or a diff. event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation for a few forms. How can I determine if a field was validated when the form was submitted rather than from a separate event, such as key up, blur, etc.?

For example in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weberonjsfiddle/3csooa8e/4/), clicking submit prints two "Validation: success" messages before a "Form submitted" message. I would like to stop the "Validation: success" messages from being printed ONLY when the form is submitted.

```
$("form").validate({
    success: function(label, element) {
        $(element).next(".help")
        .addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid");
    },
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
        return this.element(element);  
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var help = $(element).next(".help");
        if (error.html().length === 0) {
            log("Validation: success");
            help
            .addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid")
            .html(originalHelp[element.attr("id")]);
        } else {
            log("Validation: failure");
            help
            .addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid")
            .html(error.html());
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        log("Form submitted"); 
    },
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        surname: "required"
    }
});
```

Edited for clarity, hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Not clear. Add a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Apologies @sabithpocker, added the fiddle and reworded the question. Hopefully this is a bit more clear.

Comment: If you want to validate on submission you will need to be using a server side language like php, asp, or java.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve by this.  If you just want a single event to fire when the form is valid and submitted, that would simply be the `submitHandler`.

Comment: I commented on Sparky's answer--I thought an explanation for why I use jQuery Validation this way might be outside the scope of the question, but it's clearly not. I need to (1) show help on click, (2) show errors in the same spot, and (3) show the original help on valid but change the appearance of it. Perhaps I can achieve this a different way than how I've done it in the fiddle (please see that)?

Comment: I think this one does it:  http://jsfiddle.net/3csooa8e/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many issues with how you've constructed this, I don't know where to start.  Basically, you've altered the callback functions to the point where nearly every built-in feature of the plugin is broken or disabled.

1. The `errorPlacement` callback is only for *placing* the message label within the layout.  **You absolutely do not want to add/remove the error classes from within this function.**  That is what the plugin is already handling automatically.
2. The `success` callback is for placing the error label when the field is *valid*.  Typically, people use this for placing a green checkmark, etc. next to the field *after* it passes validation. It may be something you can use.

That being said, you might be able to use the `unhighlight` and `highlight` callback functions for toggling the classes... this is very close to how the plugin works by default.

```
validClass: "valid",  // default
errorClass: "invalid", // default is "error"
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
},
```

3. You do not need the `return` within your `onkeyup` function.

   ```
   onkeyup: function(element, event) {
       this.element(element);  
   },
   ```

You're also trying to use your own error messages already within your own containers.  Instead, leverage [the options provided by the plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), so that it can create and toggle errors automatically.

```
errorElement: "p", // default is 'label'
messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter a first name.",
    surname: "Please enter a surname."
}
```

Since the default error placement is immediately after the `input` element, the resulting HTML will be the same as your manually written markup from your jsFiddle.

There is still a bit of work for you to do, but hopefully this gets you a lot closer.

http://jsfiddle.net/3csooa8e/7/

---

**Quote OP's [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522474/jquery-validation-determine-if-field-was-validated-on-form-submit-or-a-diff-e/26534606?noredirect=1#comment41698778_26534606):**

> *"I have to: (1) show help on click, (2) show errors in the same spot, and (3) show the original help on valid but change the appearance of it. ...  I'm having trouble preventing the success bubbles (3) from popping up since the fields are validated."*

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3csooa8e/11/**

Same as above, except with fields already filled in:  http://jsfiddle.net/3csooa8e/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.help').show(); // shows bubble on click
    });

    $("form").validate({
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).find('.help').hide(); // hide all bubbles on valid form on button click
            log("Form submitted");
        },
        validClass: "valid",
        errorClass: "invalid",
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            surname: "required"
        },
        errorPlacement: function () {
            return false; // suppress default messages
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            // show the bubble and apply CSS for invalid
            $(element).next('.help').show().addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            // keep the bubble and apply CSS for valid
            $(element).next('.help').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: My requirements may fall outside of the use of the validation library. I have to: (1) show help on click, (2) show errors in the same spot, and (3) show the original help on valid but change the appearance of it. I thought by decoupling the library's validation from UI, I could achieve that. Everything seems to work great, except when clicking the submit button, I'm having trouble preventing the success bubbles (3) from popping up since the fields are validated. I'm starting to think that I should just roll my own simple validation library because of these requirements. Do you agree?

Comment: @weberwithoneb, perhaps or perhaps not.  There are still a lot of modifications you could do while still using the callback functions as intended.  To prevent the plugin from showing the messages is as simple as putting nothing but a `return false` within the `errorPlacement` callback function.  Then you can put whatever code you want within the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.  Since you know that `submitHandler` only fires on a valid form when the submit button is clicked, you could also put more code in there to suppress the success bubbles.